# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] - Preventing XSS and other attacks

Tags: php, forms, xss

I'm building a form where users can upload files to my server. The upload script is in PHP and is secure but I'm unsure how secure my form action is.

At the moment I do the following on submit:

```
<form id="apply" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>">
```

I've read about XSS and the $_SERVER array and how to use htmlspecialchars to secure it.

Is this enough? Should I be doing something else?

Comment: If you want to post back to the same URL, just leave action blank.

Comment: REQUEST_URI contains the requested script AND query parameters. if you're doing a POST request, there should be no need to include query parameters in the `action`. `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `action=""`, it will POST to the current page.

Comment: Now I feel really stupid... Thanks for the easiest solution ever! I'm not sure why I didn't think of this myself.

Answer (score 1):

It's not secure to directly use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] value, even if you use htmlspecialchars

Comment: Hello, what do you recommend to use other than htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ?